# What would be "openssl enc -a -e -salt -des3 -pass pass:abc123" equivalent in .NET?

Tags: .net, openssl, 3des, pkcs#5

My .Net application need to communicate with Linux based system which is using following command line to encrypt their messages:

```
openssl enc -a -e -salt -des3 -pass pass:abc123
```

How would be equivalent code to encrypt/decrypt messages in c# look like?

I understand that I should use [TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) in [CBC mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx) with [PKCS7 padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.aspx). What I don't know is what [block size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.blocksize.aspx) and [initialization vector (IV)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv.aspx) should I use.

Also I am confused how should I derive key from password. Should I use [PBKDF1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) or [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) and what salt should I use?

So what seems to be a quite standard job ends for me with all night puzzle. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here is the trick:

```
> openssl enc -a -e -salt -des3 -P -pass pass:abc123
salt=17685C0658F85BA4
key=1CB6E5A0AA4953EC2323CBA021EF008C9193F5F29990DE87
iv =9148EB5B2BF2E9B2
```

If I feed [TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) algorithm the output is almost same as openssl output. Only difference is extra 16 bytes at the beginning of the openssl output. The first eight of these bytes is "Salted__" text and the second eight is the salt.

Salt is random. So how should I derive key and iv from password and salt? [PBKDF1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) nor [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) doesn't qualify.

So here is the second trick:

```
A = MD5(pwd + SALT)
B = MD5(A + PWD + SALT)
KEY + IV = A + B
```

Plus sign stands for concatenation, Key is 24 bytes long and IV is 8 bytes long.

I learned these trick from [Deusty blog](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2009/04/decrypting-openssl-aes-files-in-c.html) where he do similar stuff with AES.